# UICollectionView header position in horizontal scroll direction mode with flow layout

Tags: ios, header, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I have ios UICollectionView with Flow layout with horizontal scroll direction.
In this situation typical header position is on the left side of cells.

I want to make header on the top of section cells

Have you any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I think you can get what you need using standard behavior for the header.

Set it up (probably in viewDidLoad):

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, 30);
// other setup
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

Then answer a header view:

```
#define MY_HEADER_LABEL_TAG 128

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:
                                            UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"SectionHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[headerView viewWithTag:MY_HEADER_LABEL_TAG];
    if (!label) {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(headerView.bounds, 5, 5)];
        label.tag = MY_HEADER_LABEL_TAG;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        [headerView addSubview:label];
    }

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", indexPath.section];
    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: @greg_pl Did you get this working? If so, how did you end up doing it?

Comment: This does not make sense - How should this solve the question?

Comment: This solution is impossible to get what your want.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem using [DateFlowLayout](https://gist.github.com/vigorouscoding/5155703).

See how I configured it in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17834603/72508).

Comment: upvote with comment — thanks for the links, helped me with a similar problem :)

Comment: Not working for me. Any changes have to do in DateFlowLayout?