# UICollectionView special horizontal flow - multiple sections

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView there is used differently depending on device orientation. The image describe what I have and what I need.

Is it possible to get "Horizontal scrolling as I need it" with default flowlayout or do I need to make customflowlayout(Guide appreciated) or multiple collectionviews?

[image: Collection flow layout]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it using [DateFlowLayout](https://gist.github.com/vigorouscoding/5155703). Strange name but it works, with some configurations.

This was my setup to you it(I only used it for the horizontal direction):

```
- (void)layoutForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    bool isPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation);

    self.collectionView.frame = isPortrait ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 180) : CGRectMake(0, 60, 246, 595);
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = isPortrait ? DateFlowLayout.new : UICollectionViewFlowLayout.new;
    self.flowLayout = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout);

    self.flowLayout.scrollDirection = isPortrait ? UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal : UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    self.flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = isPortrait ? CGSizeMake(5, 30) : CGSizeMake(246, 40); //width is margin to the left of the header - must be bigger than 0 to show headers correct.
    self.flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = isPortrait ? 10 : 0;
    self.flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = isPortrait ? 17 : 7;
    self.flowLayout.sectionInset = isPortrait ? UIEdgeInsetsMake(27, 30, 25, 0) : UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 0);
    //self.flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(58, 85); //You might need this
    self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = isPortrait ? NO : YES;
}
```

Comment: Hey Morten, I know it's been a while but any ideas why my header is sticking but not on top of my collection view, rather in front of it, positioned halfway (heightwise). Thanks!

Comment: fair enough. i'll do a bit more of that too then! at least i know it's possible :)

Comment: Do you have swift version?

Comment: does not compile for me as well

Comment: Regarding "it does not compile" - remember it is a post from 2013, a lot have changed in the language since. It did compile back then, so with some googling it should be possible to find the changes and use the principles.

Comment: Does anyone have swift version?