# Display section header on top with UICollectionViewFlowLayout scrolling set to horizontal

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579535/uicollectionview-header-position-in-horizontal-scroll-direction-mode-with-flow-l). I'm asking again because the accepted answer is not working and no one's providing more explanation on how the supposed correct answer works.

So here's the situation: I want to display the collection view into one single row. To do this, I applied a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to the collection view and set the scrolling to horizontal. Everything is working fine, except for section header disappeared.

[image: Header disappeared]

To remedy this, I implemented this function:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
  {
    return CGSizeMake(350, 35);
  }
```

Now the header is shown, but the problem is it is displayed to the left of the cells, instead of the usual top.

I stumbled upon the link above while searching for a solution, but like I've said, the accepted answer is not working at all and I could not find other solutions about this situation. So can anyone help me here?

[image: Wrong header position]

Comment: I am facing the same problem now. How could you manage it?
If you have to solution please share with me.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Tulon. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any solution for this. I decided to create a custom view instead.

Comment: Hi Anna. I managed this with an alternative solution. I did it with multiple `UICollectionView`. It's easy to do and handy a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

we can do that by using the delegate method  -

```
(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
```

and keeping the left inset to minus value of width of supplementary view and managing the top inset

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the header with something like this?

First: set it up in viewDidLoad...

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, 30);
// add any other setup you need
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

Second: add header view ...

```
#define LABEL_TAG 128

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:
                                            UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"SectionHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[headerView viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG];
    if (!label) {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(headerView.bounds, 5, 5)];
        label.tag = MY_HEADER_LABEL_TAG;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [headerView addSubview:label];
    }

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %d", indexPath.section];
    return headerView;
}
```